# Compare 2 txt and get total count excluding repetitions

Tags: python

I have two files .txt and I should compare them and just count common words. What I should get is just a total count of how many words in common 2 different files have. How I can do it? Can you help me? This is the code that I have try, but I need only the total count ex "I have found 125 occurrences" (excluding repetitions)

Comment: what's the problem with your code, the dict doesn't output what you want ?

Comment: Did you strip ```\n```. Also, can you please provide and example of text files

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We don't write code for you, and it would rob you of the joy of learning the Python. Here's a hint. I'm guessing that you want to see how many of the words in text1.txt are  *not* in verbs.txt. Instead of putting it into a list, could you make dct a dictionary?

Comment: @rajah9 `dct` is already a dictionary?

Comment: @MustafaAydın you are right, the `dct = {}` makes it an empty dict.

Answer (score 1):

for example if you have
`verbs.txt`

```
it
hello
world
```

`text.txt`

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when 
an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make 
a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset 
sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with 
desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

you can use the given script to Count How much times it words from `verbs.txt` occurred in `text.txt`

```py
import re

pattern = r'\b\S+\b'

res = {}

with open("verbs.txt") as vb:
    search_words = set([word.lower() for word in vb.read().split("\n")])

with open("text.txt") as text:
    data = text.read()
    words = [word.lower() for word in re.findall(pattern, data)]



for word in words:
    if word in search_words:
        res[word] = res.get(word, 0) + 1

print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is python a requirement for this? If you are on UNIX machine, you can very efficiently do this with some bash code:

```sh
comm -12 <(
sort verbs.txt ) <(
sort text1.txt ) | uniq | wc -l
```

the option `-12` makes sure you just pick the common words, the two `sort` commands are entered in two different subshells, it is then piped into a `uniq` command (you include this if you want just unique elements), finally you count the words with the `wc -l` command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [intersection of the sets](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_set_intersection.asp)

```
words1 = { 'a', 'b', 'c' }
words2 = { 'b', 'c', 'd' }

common_words = words1.intersection(words2) # { 'b', 'c' }

print(len(common_words)) # output: 2
```

The way how you can obtain the sets from your files is in the answer of @Giorgi Imerlishvili.

Comment: Do you have the txt files?